# How to refresh authentication token in Axios with parallel responses?

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, refresh-token

I want to implement JWT authentication in a react app using Axios.
There are many solutions using `axios.interceptors` that fetch the token again if the request failed due to the authentication error.
Example:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    return response;
},function(error) {
    const originalReq = error.config;
    if ( error.response.status == 401 && 
         !originalReq._retry && 
         error.response.config.url != URL_USER_AUTHENTICATE ) {
        originalReq._retry = true;
        return axios.post(BASE_URL+URL_REFRESH_TOKEN,{})
                    .then((res) =>{
                        if ( res.data.status == "success") {
                            return axios(originalReq);
                        } 
                    }).catch((error) => {window.location.href="/logout/nosession"});
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

However, it doesn't work if we have parallel requests. Imagine that we have two parallel requests, so both will request the new authentication token.

Does anybody know any fix?

Comment: According to logic, request *b* can't know request *a* is authenticated when request *a* didn't receive a response yet. So you'll have to wait for request *a* to finish before you can run request *b* to avoid this from happening (perhaps by setting a boolean variable to true when requesting.)

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the JWT expiry on each page load, and then set a timer to request for new token near the expiry. This will avoid the token expire scenario altogether. This can be done in your authentication Provider.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial It could still happen that the request returns a 401, e.g. if the access token is revoked by the server, or if the server keeps access tokens in memory and is restarted. (I know that usually then the refresh token expires then too, but you can't know for sure how the server is implemented.)

Answer (score 2):

My example React SPA has some code that manages this, and may give you some ideas for your own solution. The third class below uses a technique of handling a list of promises but only making the remote call on one of them, then returning the same result to all callers.

- [API 401 logic](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiFetch.ts#L29)
- [Refresh trigger](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts#L154)
- [Concurrency handler](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/utilities/concurrentActionHandler.ts)

An alternatiive solution can be to do a silent refresh in a background timer when the token is close to expiry, based on the `expires_in` field returned with the access token. But that is not fully reliable since 401s can occur for multiple reasons, eg due to some types of infrastructure or server key changes, so I have always written 401 handling in clients, to ensure reliability.